# Nvidia driver installation results in resolution change to 800x600 with Xubuntu 10.04 (can't change)

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, resolution

I have a 2.8 P4 and a Nvidia FX 5500 AGP graphics card. I've installed Xubuntu 10.04. It is WAY too laggy with the default o/s driver. Installing the Nvidia 173 driver, `modaliases` and `nvidia-settings` packages via synaptic package manager results in the following error message:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right click
>   menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong. Error: Opening the
>   cache (E::read, still have 11898251 to read but none left, E: The
>   package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.) This
>   usually means that your installed packages have unmet dependencies.

When restarting the PC the resolution drops to 800x600 (from the monitors native 1440x900).

Nvidia settings cannot be changed either from the Xfce menu or Nvidia Xserver. Nvidia Xsever gives the following error message:

> You do not appear to be using the Nvidia X driver. Please edit your x
>   configuration file (just run 'nvidiaxconfig' as root ) and restart X
>   server.

Also, I can't find anything in any directory called xorg.

Answer (score 0):

Nvidia package has not installed properly, (dependency problem) therefore after resolving crashing issue, it is uninstalled again.
Now you have not any installed driver and resolution goes 800x600.

- Try  **Additional Driver** tool for installing NVidia driver automatically.
- Try installing Nvidia proprietary driver. If you failed to installing that, try to installing "Vesa" driver.
- Also you can use following PPA to installing NVidia driver
  `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates

  sudo apt-get update

  sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

from what I believe, there was a failure to install the given packages.
Remove the drivers and then reinstall them, and it should work just fine. If there are any broken packages,  just use the "fix broken packages" in synaptic as I see that you're already using synaptic.

Comment: PS - you might wanna clear the ./var/cache/apt/archives folder before because sometimes, the downloaded packages are broken. Happens rarely though.